# Click even on button not Working if it has a span inside ( it works only when i click near border ) JS

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, model-view-controller

```
                                <button class="anunt-edit" type="submit" data-id="@anunt.Id" id="editButton" >
                                    @Html.Partial("editSVGPartial", new {@Id="editButton", @class="svg"})
                                </button>
```

The Html Helper partial is for an Edit icon span,
the problem is that in javascript e.target.matches("#editButton") returns true only when i click the button near border ( i think it doesnt work properly because of the span that is inside )

```
document.addEventListener("click", e => 
    {
        var isEditButtonClicked = e.target.matches("#editButton");
        if ( isEditButtonClicked )
        {
            console.log("button clicked")
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("click")
        }
    })
```

Comment: try 
const button = document.getElementById("editButton");
button.addEventListener("click", e => { console.log('button is clicked')});

Comment: I guess that your button is covered by the span inside. You could try to use browser Developer Tool to find out ID of the span, then listen click event for both of the button and the span inside.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the id of the span to the same one as the id of the button that is the direct parent and now it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).